# Tapered 8-sided cylinder with smooth shading is not very smooth

Tags: mesh

I have an 8-sided cylinder that gradually tapers in, as a cone would. I'm using it as a funnel. The issue is that the cone part is kind of choppy despite smooth shading being enabled. The funny thing is that the cylinder extruding from the cone itself is pretty smooth.

In the 8-sided cone, the faces are easily distinguishable from each other which is what I'm trying to avoid.

[image]

TIA for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly due to lack of resolution in the mesh. Adding a Subdivision Surface modifier should fix this.